# How to find which IP address is used by EC2 instance when it's making requests to some other server outwards

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ip

So I am fairly new when it comes to working with AWS/EC2. I know that you can assign elastic IP which are static and they direct all the incoming requests to my ec2 instance.

What I want to know is, if it is same IP used by instance when it's making a request outwards?

Suppose I use my instance to open a webpage, which IP will that webpage see? Is there a way for me to make this outward IP static?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

If an Amazon EC2 instance in a public subnet has an Elastic IP address, and software on the instance is making an outbound request to something on the Internet, the request will come "from" that Elastic IP address.

(The truth is a little more complex, but it's easier just to think of it this way. Cloud stuff, you know!)

Comment: What do you mean public subnet? Do I need to do anything other than making an ec2 instance and giving it an elastic IP?

Comment: Subnets can be pubic (connected to the Internet with a Route Table connection that points to an Internet Gateway) or private (no Internet Gateway). For an instance to communicate directly with the Internet, it will need to be in a public subnet. If you access that instance from the Internet, it is already in a public subnet. I only mentioned it because an instance in a _private_ subnet connect directly communicate with the Internet even if it has an Elastic IP address.